# Converting a string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

How do you make JS think that a string is JSON ?

I have a function which only works if JSON object is passed to it. If I pass a string to it, with same format as JSON, it doesn't work. So I want to make that function think that the string passed to it is a JSON. The string is indeed in the JSON format.

I also tried the following. I inputted the string through Ajax , with "handle as" parameter as "JSON", and then when  I passed the result to the function it works.

So I deduced the problem is not with the string. How do I convert this string to JSON? If i get same string through ajax request and then passing it to function works, whereas directly passing it doesn't work.

The string is as follows:

```
  {
     "data": [
   {
  "id": "id1",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "name1",
          "label": "joker",
          "unit": "year"
        },
         {"id": "name2", "label": "Quantity"},
    ],
      "rows": [    data here....

and closing braces..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: Your title is misleading. Based on the content of your question I'd rather say you want to convert a string containing JSON into a JavaScript object/array.

Comment: OK i solved it. There was a \n in the string. Now only have to figure out how to use JSON.parse with this.

Comment: Ok i fixed it. Goto http://jsonlint.com/ and put your string there. If it says its correct, then you can use JSONParse to achieve the same.

Comment: In case anyone reads this, the title is supposed to be "converting a JSON string into an object"

Answer (score 416, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Where `string` is your json string.

Comment: This is not working. It is throwing an error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" . There is nothing wrong with the string as when i get the same string through a ajax request and handle it as "JSON", no problem occurs.

Comment: please post your acutal JSON string

Comment: { "data": [ { id": - you are missing a double quote here, i.e. starting double quote of id

Comment: I have no idea why SO removed it. Its present in the string. it is  { "data": [ { "id"

Comment: When I get it through Ajax it works as then it handles the response as JSON . So I think I have to convert this to a JSON object..

Comment: even now the extra comma after '"Quantity"}, ' looks suspicious. You need to share your entire json string for us to know. JSON.parse() is a standard approach and should work for all valid json strings.

Comment: I ended up going to jsonlint.com, and making sure my Json is right

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `JSON.parse()` for that.

[See docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

**Example:**

```
var myObj = JSON.parse('{"p": 5}');
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: This is not working. It is throwing an error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character" . There is nothing wrong with the string as when i get the same string through a ajax request and handle it as "JSON", no problem occurs.

Comment: @Zer0: You should update your question with how you are trying it along with your json string.

Comment: @Zer0: We can only answer to the best of our knowledge. You say you have a JSON string, we answer accordingly. It seems your string is different, if you'd post it, we can answer taking this into account. If you ask a question about coding, then code/data is indispensable .

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a similar string like yours

```
{id:1,field1:"someField"},{id:2,field1:"someOtherField"}
```

The problem here is the structure of the string. The json parser wasn't recognizing that it needs to create 2 objects in this case. So what I did is kind of silly, I just re-structured my string and added the `[]` with this the parser recognized

```
var myString = {id:1,field1:"someField"},{id:2,field1:"someOtherField"}
myString = '[' + myString +']'
var json = $.parseJSON(myString)
```

Hope it helps,

If anyone has a more elegant approach please share.

Comment: In your code above, you've constructed `myString` incorrectly. It's not a string, and it's incorrectly formatted JSON. Your second line would then become redundant.

Here's what it should be:

    `var myString = '[{"id":1,"field1":"someField"},{"id":2,"field1":"someOtherField"}]'`


I know this is quite an old post, but I thought I'd add some clarity in case anyone finds it.

Comment: I solved my issue using `$.parseJSON` where `JSON.parse` was not working and throwing an error *`JSON.parse is not a function`*

Answer (score 5):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

link:-

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `eval` function.

```
var myJson = eval(theJsibStr);
```

Comment: eval is evil, be very careful to security with this approach

Answer (score 4):

convert the string to HashMap using Object Mapper ...

`new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, Map.class);`

Internally Map will behave as JSON Object

Answer (score 2):

```
var Data=[{"id": "name2", "label": "Quantity"}]
```

Pass the string variable into Json parse :

```
Objdata= Json.parse(Data);
```

Comment: In your example, `Data` is already an object, so there would be no need to parse it. You would need some quotes surrounding all your Data in order to make it a string.

Answer (score 2):

Let's us consider you have string like

example : **"name:lucy,age:21,gender:female"**

```js
function getJsonData(query){
    let arrayOfKeyValues = query.split(',');
    let modifiedArray =  new Array();
    console.log(arrayOfKeyValues);
    for(let i=0;i< arrayOfKeyValues.length;i++){
        let arrayValues = arrayOfKeyValues[i].split(':');
        let arrayString ='"'+arrayValues[0]+'"'+':'+'"'+arrayValues[1]+'"';
        modifiedArray.push(arrayString);
    }
    let jsonDataString = '{'+modifiedArray.toString()+'}';
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(typeof jsonData);
    return jsonData;
}

let query = "name:lucy,age:21,gender:female";
let response = getJsonData(query);
console.log(response);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` function will do.

or

Using Jquery,

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "Vinod" }' );
alert( obj.name === "Vinod" );
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` is your friend. Here's an example:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(yourString)
console.log(typeof obj); // prints 'object' assuming your string is correctly formatted
```