# convert json to javascript object for datables

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I want to convert json into a javascript object but i am unable to do so,since i am new.

```
{"campaigns":{"campDetails":[{"campaign_id":"1012","campaign_name":"RP - Axe Sample (Submit)"}]}}
```

into

```
"columns": [
            { "data": {} },
            { "data": "hr.position" },
            { "data": "contact.0" },
            { "data": "contact.1" },
            { "data": "hr.start_date" },
            { "data": "hr.salary" }
        ]
```

javascript object format the above is the javasctipt object to another another json. Just avoid the data I needed to know how you parse example

```
    "columns" : [{data:campaigndetails{ _:campaigns }}]
```

etc is want the out put be like

```
columns:[
{data:1012}.
{data:RP - Axe Sample (Submit)}
]
```

but i dont really know the parameters

Comment: The two objects have nothing in common. How do you get from one to the other? Converting a JSON **string** to a javascript **Object** is a simple as `JSON.parse(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ - That has a good API for your task.
Else, check [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object) - Somewhat similar to your problem.

Comment: What is it in the OP that makes `jQuery.parseJSON` preferable to `JSON.parse`? Anything?

Comment: Nothing particular.. just what makes jQuery preferable to plain old java script (:

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval to convert any string into json

```
var str = {"campaigns":{"campDetails":[{"campaign_id":"1012","campaign_name":"RP - Axe Sample (Submit)"}]}};
var obj = eval(str);
```

Comment: but sir how do i use it to alert example alert(obj.campaign_id) is giving not defined error

Comment: try this alert(obj.campaigns.campDetails[0].campaign_id);