# Convert String of certain format to JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, dictionary

I have a string of the format

```
 var str = "{key1=value1, Key2=value2}"
```

I need to convert this into a json object to be able to iterate through it.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? there can be any number of keys

Comment: What is your idea? This is not a free coding service

Comment: Hint: You need to make sure that the keys are surrounded by quotes (like "key1") and that the equal signs are being replaced with colons

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow discussion! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object

Comment: This discussion doesn't match the question

Comment: I am receiving a jsp hashmap as a parameter to a file. it is being passed using the <jsp:param> tag and as a result its being converted to a string of the above format.

Comment: @Vignesh https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/  You can do it in java too

Answer (score 2):

You need first to "JSONize" this string you are getting so it can be converted to a JavaScript object using the `JSON` class. My guess, if the string has always this format (`{key=value, ...}`), is that you could parse it first like this:

```
var parsedString = yourString.replace(/(\b\S+\b)=(\b\S+\b)/g, '"$1":"$2"')
```

This way, from this: `"{key1=value1, Key2=value2}"` you get this: `'{"key1":"value1", "Key2":"value2"}'`.

Then, as someone suggested, just use `JSON.parse(parsedString)` to get your JS object.