# How to create JSON object from below text JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need to create an object from the given variable string.

```
var text ='{"Origin":"Hybris","country":"Germany","Email":"senthilkumar@yopmail.com","Businesstype": "Global","region": "EMEA", "lang": "en_US}"}'
```

Comment: Is the text correctly pasted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object)

Comment: You should utilize the code snippet feature in the editor to better display your code. It will show formatting and could can help others to see issue.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps

```js
let text = '{"Origin":"Hybris","country":"Germany","Email":"senthilkumar@yopmail.com","Businesstype":"Global","region":"EMEA","lang":"en_US"}';

let json = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse(string)` Parses the string into the javascript object and
`JSON.stringify(obj)` Converts the Javascript object into String.
In your scenario `JSON.parse` would do the job.
Try using:

```
let text = '{"Origin":"Hybris","country":"Germany","Email":"senthilkumar@yopmail.com","Businesstype":"Global","region":"EMEA","lang":"en_US"}';
let json = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(json);
```

Hope this helps.