# convert sting (object of object) in object

Tags: javascript, css, json, api

I have an API response in string

```
"{"div":{"display": "flex","flexDirection": "column","alignItems":"center","fontFamily":"Helvetica Neue"},"a":{"fontSize": 16, "textAlign": "center","fontWeight":"bold","color":"#324F85"},"p":{"fontSize": 34,"textAlign":"center","color": "#7f8f96d"},"h5": {"fontWeight": "normal","fontSize": 18,"textAlign":"center"}}"
```

I want to convert the string to object like

```
{div:{display: 'flex',flexDirection: 'column',alignItems: 'center',fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},a: {fontSize: 16,textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold',color: '#324F85'}, p:{fontSize: 34,textAlign: 'center',color: '#7f8f96d6'},h5: { fontWeight: 'normal',fontSize: 18,textAlign: 'center'}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object)

Comment: @Kordrad not exactly applicable, since OP has invalid JSON.

Comment: @VLAZ why its invalid ?

Comment: JSON requires keys and string values to be in double quotes. Your data uses single quotes.

Comment: @VLAZ i have updated question (data in  double quotes) still its giving Error: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Because the outer quotes are also double. Your string is terminated early. Look at the syntax highlighting and you'll see it's not all just one string. Whatever you are doing in order to produce the JSON *you should fix that* to produce valid JSON. Currently, it seems you're just trying to match some sort of valid syntax by hand. There are plenty of tools that will generate JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function like so:

```
const apiResponseAsObject = JSON.parse(apiResponseAsString)
```

---

For future questions, please format your code as actual code.

Comment: This will not work because OP's string is not valid JSON.

Comment: thanks for replay, i already tried this, but its not working, error: Unexpected ' in JSON at position 1